# Can the blk0001.dat and blk0002.dat files be deleted?

Tags: blockchain

I have a Bitcoin installation on an SD card, and the blockchain files (`blk0001.dat` specifically) take up nearly 4 GB of disk space.

Can the `blk0001.dat` and `blk0002.dat` files be safely deleted to free up space on my SD card? Will the blockchain just be downloaded again next time I run my bitcoin client?

Comment: You can use a symlink to put the wallet.dat on your SD card while the rest of the data files are including the blockchain are on your hard drive, if you wish.

Comment: Good idea @StephenGornick!

Comment: It's a bad idea to symlink wallet.dat! If your client ever shuts down non-cleanly, you may end up with a corrupt wallet.

Answer (score 8):

You can delete them just fine, as long as you delete blkindex.dat too. They will be downloaded and processed again. This will take a while, these days, though.

Comment: Thanks! A while meaning hours... or weeks? :-)

Comment: @Josh: YMMV but may be about a day. For this purpose you should consider trying a lightweight client.

Comment: From my personal experience Days (About 1 hour for each week you are behind). This is for my 2.4 Ghz machine. Infinite patience.