# safely delete the blockchain from .bitcoin directory

Tags: bitcoind, blockchain, storage-footprint

I have bitcoind installed and I'd like to free up space by deleting the blockchain from my .bitcoin directory. What set of files and directories should I delete such that the next time I start bitcoind it will recover gracefully by downloading the blockchain again?

Comment: related: [Can the blk0001.dat and blk0002.dat files be deleted?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/4594/5406)

Answer (score 4):

Delete the "blocks" and "chainstate" directories.